# How to add mask for component input text bootsfaces?

Tags: input, bootsfaces

I would like to know how to add mask for component input text bootsfaces

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for the inputSecret? https://showcase.bootsfaces.net/forms/inputSecret.jsf

Answer (score 0):

**Update May, 23 2017:** Jasper de Vries provided a pull request to BootsFaces implemting the input mask. So the feature will be part of BootsFaces 1.1.1+ (i.e. 1.1.2 or higher).

**Original answer:**
We haven't implemented this feature yet (see https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/267). But I'm sure you can add it using the i[nput mask of Robin Herbots](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask).

If you want the BootsFaces team to prioritize the feature, please tell us on [our bug tracker](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/267). Thanks!

Comment: can you give me an example? Because I didn't get it

Comment: I've created a pull request. So you might expect it in one of the coming releases.

Answer (score 0):

Examples of predifined Mask:

```
<b:inputText value="#{bean.val}" mask="numeric" label="numeric input"/>

<b:inputText value="#{bean.val2}" mask="alphabetical" label="alphabetical input"/>

<b:inputText value="#{bean.val3}" mask="alphanumeric" label="alphanumeric input" />
```